# more than one AVG column with diffrent conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as follows:

```
id   year  value
1     2012   10
2     2013    7
3     2013    7
4     2014    8
5     2014    10
6     2015    6
7     2011    12
```

I need to write a query which gives the AVG value of the last 4 years from today. Meaning that if today is 2016 then the AVG is on 2015,2014,2013.

Basicly this could be done with 3 queries:

```
Select avg(value) as a
from tab
where year=2015
```

and

```
Select avg(value) as b
from tab
where year=2014
```

and

```
Select avg(value) as c
from tab
where year=2013
```

The results based on the given values should be:

```
2013   7
2014   9
2015   6
```

Since all of them is on the same table... How can I do that in one query (postgresql)?
it should be without a WHERE.

Something like:

```
Select avg(with condition) as a, avg(with condition) as b, avg(with condition) as c
from tab
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `group by` year and constrict to the years you want in your `where` clause

```
select avg(value), year
from tab
where year in (2013,2014,2015)
group by year
```

The query above will give you 3 separate rows. If you prefer a single row then you can use conditional aggregation instead of a `group by`

```
select 
    avg(case when year = 2013 then value end) as avg_2013,
    avg(case when year = 2014 then value end) as avg_2014,
    avg(case when year = 2015 then value end) as avg_2015,
from tab
where year in (2013,2014,2015)
```

Comment: This answer is somewhat good but not scalable. Suppose a new year greater than 2016 is inserted into the table, that will mean you will need to adjust your where clause!

Comment: @cdaiga I gave years maualy as an example. Of curse I will adjust the query to work with  extracting the last 3 years from Current_Date. This answer is simple to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    avg(case when year = date_part('year', NOW()) then value end) as avg_2016,
    avg(case when year = ((date_part('year', NOW())) - 1 ) then value end) as avg_2015,
    avg(case when year = ((date_part('year', NOW())) - 2 ) then value end) as avg_2014,
     avg(case when year = ((date_part('year', NOW())) - 3 ) then value end) as avg_2013
from tab
```

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name  I think Now query is fine